# 404 error after loading JS file from html?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, http-status-code-404

I am getting a 404 error when the site loads my JS file. The JS file appears in Network but with a 404 error. The JS file loads fine locally but the problem is after I deployed. I am using Netlify to deploy my site.

Here is the link to the [Site](https://manage-home-abdev.netlify.app/)

Here is the link to  [Github Repository](https://github.com/abdulrehmandev/manage-landing-page)

Thanks in advance for looking into my problem

I have tried renaming file and relocating files. I thought maybe I was including SwiperJS from CDN links and it may be causing the problem. I then installed it to the folder as well and imported it locally. I thought the problem was in loading the file but it is not the case. Network shows the file is loaded but with a 404 error. I couldn't find anything helpful over internet.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Firt of all, i have checked your Github repository and i found that index.js is not being moved to the dist folder. so, you may have to use vite configuration to move index.js file to dist folder. you are using import statement so, you must use **index.mjs** means .mjs extension.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the path nor due to external library. I was using vite to build my project and I had not added the type="module" in the script tag. That was leading to this problem. Thank you all who considered to look into my problem.